# How to query Azure SQL DB from Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database

I want to query Azure SQL DB from Azure DevOps release pipeline. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be using powershell [Invoke-sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) In a powershell task in Azure Devops.

Example:

```bsh
$return = Invoke-Sqlcmd 
   -ConnectionString $DBCONNECTIONSTRING ` 
   -InputFile $PSScriptRoot/Create-DbApiUser.sql ` 
   -Variable @("password=$Password","username=$Username")
```

This example uses a full connection string and an input file as the SQL query. You don't need that however and you can write the SQL query in PowerShell itself.
You can also pass variables to the SQL query as in the example.
Also, the $return also to get the table data into a PowerShell variable and work further with that.

It also depends what you want to achieve. Invoke-sqlcmd has its limitations.

You have also a dedicated AzureDevops task:

```yaml
    - task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
      inputs:
        AuthenticationType: 'server'
        ServerName: '$Sqlservername'
        DatabaseName: '$Databasename'
        SqlUsername: '$Login'
        SqlPassword: '$Password'
        deployType: 'InlineSqlTask'
        SqlInline: 'SELECT * FROM foo'
        IpDetectionMethod: 'AutoDetect'
```

Note, to access the database you have to set the firewall [settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-sqldb?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) on the sql server to either:

1. Allow Azure services and resources to access this server.
2. If 1 is not an option, add a powershell task as showed in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-sqldb?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to add and remove firewall rules so the pipeline can connect to the database.

Comment: Thank you. I will check the connectivity and update here.

Comment: I tried this. Im getting login error. My credentials are correct, still giving the login error. The same credentials are working from SSMS.

Comment: Edited the main response. I would assume the issue are the firewall settings on the SQL server.

Comment: Is there any way to connect to Azure SQL using Azure PowerShell. the Firewall option is not working for me. I know this is the correct option as you mentioned in the documentation. If there is any Powershell option to connect to sql I will try that or will mark this as an answer because this is the right approach.

Comment: The first code sample shows how to query Azure SQL, you still need a connection string to execute the query. You could also try using a Service Principal like in this article:
https://stefanstranger.github.io/2018/06/06/ConnectToAzureSqlDatabaseByObtainingATokenFromAzureActiveDirectoryAad/